# How can a back-end server connect to a specific iphone?

Tags: iphone

It is very usual that an iPhone send data to internet server.
But what if a server wants to connect to an iphone?
I have wondered long about it.
For example, like many web-based apps like Facebook, what is the mechanism/algorithm behind, so that when, for example, any updates on your wall can be noticed to you in a real-time manner?

Hope some can understand my query.

Answer (score 0):

Have a look at this Wikpedia article about [Push Technology](http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Push_technology).

> Push technology, or server push, describes a style of Internet-based communication where the request for a given transaction is initiated by the publisher or central server. It is contrasted with pull technology, where the request for the transmission of information is initiated by the receiver or client.

Answer (score 0):

1. Your iPhone could intermittently 'poll' the server, looking for any data it needs to be sent. Say every 5 seconds, or after some trigger - it would call the server and ask for new data.
2. You could use push technology: i.e. have a continuous http connection open to your server that allows data to be sent both ways. LightStreamer is a product that does this that i've used before. This is the most elegant and efficient solution for streaming data.
3. You could use iOS push notifications. The server can trigger a push message and target it at a specific device and send your iPhone something...

Answer (score 0):

Push notifications are the way to go with iOS. I have used push notifications through the cloud-based [Cocoafish backend server](http://www.cocoafish.com). This is a great solution as you can 'subscribe' mobile devices to a push notifications channel - for example, a channel for friends requests or a channel for chat etc. Its real easy to set up with all the correct certification. There's good set up instructions in the documentation on their site too.